# how can I use the Metapost language in LuaLatex to set watermark for page?

Tags: luatex, context-lmtx

I am completely new to ConTeXt and have just started to experiment with writing metapost directly within ConTeXt. In ConTeXt , I use the following Metapost code to set watermark for one page and my question is how can I use the Metapost language in LuaLatex to set watermark  for page?

```
\startuseMPgraphic{square}
path p; p := fullsquare xscaled 8cm yscaled 6cm;
draw p rotated 45 randomized 30mm
withcolor transparent (1, .5 randomized .3, darkgray)
withpen pencircle scaled 2pt;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[watermark][\useMPgraphic{square}]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=watermark]

\starttext
\setupbodyfont[dejavu,12pt]
\input knuth
\input zapf
\input knuth
\input zapf
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `draftwatermark` package and the `luamplib` package to do this.   Here is one possible approach:  put the MP graphic in a box, and use that box as the watermark text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\mplibsetformat{metafun}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox\mpbox
\savebox\mpbox{\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(0);
path p; p := fullsquare xscaled 8cm yscaled 6cm;
draw p rotated 45 randomized 30mm
withcolor transparent (1, .5 randomized .3, darkgray)
withpen pencircle scaled 2pt;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}}

\DraftwatermarkOptions{text={\usebox\mpbox}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` to get a PDF that looks something like this:

[image]

Links: [documentation about `luamplib`](https://ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en), and more on [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your enthusiasm